# Print date and sha512 sum to file?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wanted to print the date and the sha512 sum into a file, preferably with this syntax: `<date> : <sha512sum>`.

The code is this:

```
FILES="
blocklists/blocklist.txt
whitelists/whitelist.txt
"
main() {
    echo "sha512"
    func_sha512sum
    cat sha512.md
}

func_sha512sum() {
    for file in $FILES
    do
        sha512sum $file > temp2
        date > temp3
        temp3 + " : " + temp2 >> sha512.md
    done
}
main
rm temp*
```

but the output is just this:

```
sha512
test.sh: 17: temp3: not found
test.sh: 17: temp3: not found
```

does someone know how to get that to work? thanks in advance

edit: without the rm temp* both temp2 and temp3 are filled with the information they should be, but it won't "merge" them into the sha512sum.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line isn't doing anything useful in bash syntax:

```
temp3 + " : " + temp2 >> sha512.md
```

That means "take the string `temp3` and run it as a command, passing it `+ " : " + temp2` as arguments and append the output to the file `sha512.md`". Here's a working version of your script:

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash
FILES="
blocklists/blocklist.txt
whitelists/whitelist.txt
"
main() {
    echo "sha512"
    func_sha512sum
    cat sha512.md
}

func_sha512sum() {
    for file in $FILES
    do
      printf '%s : %s\n' \
            "$(date)" \
            "$(sha512sum -- "$file")"  >> sha512.md
    done
}
main
```

Personally, I would avoid hardcoding the file names though since that really limits the script. Just take the files from the arguments and print to standard output:

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

for file in "$@"; do
  printf '%s : %s\n' \
        "$(date)" \
        "$(sha512sum -- "$file")"  
done
```

You would then run it like this:

```
$ foo.sh whitelists/whitelist.txt blocklists/blocklist.txt 
Fri Apr 23 10:11:10 AM BST 2021 : a61788166e55f4fbac36f7c9b5a35b80d79eaee684e247caa1e3985a0b78a0edd2c04cacad017b077250c91ced64894d3ae17204df684e09020d7d2569414c5c  blocklists/blocklist.txt
Fri Apr 23 10:11:10 AM BST 2021 : 6b29fcb04c0c19abda792b6efb41f317d8a6af63daad74c0eb82ac7dee7be88d87242fb36b56c63581f109d8cb50969b519935d23b9c5223af1c69a4e3ac5ef5  whitelists/whitelist.txt
```

Comment: thanks, that did it, tho i've changed it so it puts it to the sha512.md because of the lists can't contain something like that

Comment: well that did not really the trick, where do i add that it should store the date and sha512sum output into the sha512.md file?

Comment: @ash3781 I don't know what you mean. What "list" can't contain something like what? As for storing in a file, if you are using the second option, just redirect the output like any other program: `foo.sh whitelists/whitelist.txt blocklists/blocklist.txt > sha512.md`. The first option already writes to that file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be using `temp3` as a command.  It olse seems to mix shell code with something that may be Python.  The shell does not do concatenation with `+`.  You also can't put filenames in a string variable and then extract them from that string without severely limiting the types of names that you can support.  It's better to use a real array variable for lists of things.

Assuming you want the ordinary output format of `sha256sum` for your files, and each prefixed (on the same line) with the output of `date`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

files=(
    blocklists/blocklist.txt
    whitelists/whitelist.txt
)

now=$(date)

for filepath in "${files[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$now" |
    paste -d : - <( sha256sum -- "$filepath" )
done >sha256.md
```

This uses an array for the files (this allows for all possible filenames, also filename with spaces, newlines, and globbing characters), and it uses `paste` to create two columns with the output of `date` in the first column and the output of `sha256sum` in the other.  The two columns are delimited by `:`.

Changing this script to run on whatever names you give on the script's command line, and writing the output to standard output:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date)

for filepath do
    printf '%s\n' "$now" |
    paste -d : - <( sha256sum -- "$filepath" )
done
```

You'd use this like so:

```
$ ./myscript blocklists/blocklist.txt whitelists/whitelist.txt >sha256.md
```

---

Or, you could get rid of the need for looping and just call `sha256sum` with all the given pathnames:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sha256sum "$@" |
awk -v now="$(date)" -v OFS=: '{ print now, $0 }'
```

Comment: Note that if there are enough files to make your last command run for more than a second, the date won't be accurate since `now="$(date)"` is only evaluated once when you launch the script. No idea if that will be an issue for the OP of course since it would require a significant number of files and that the OP cares for an accuracy of seconds.